# Non-zero IOSTAT status when creating a scratch file

Tags: fortran

I have the following Fortran code. Please explain me..

```
OPEN(UNIT=4,STATUS='SCRATCH',ACCESS='DIRECT',RECL=2048,IOSTAT=IOCHK)
```

Here IOCHK is not initialized to 0, it is giving some garbage value so that my code is not working..

```
IF(IOCHK.NE.0)THEN
// failed code
```

Can i initialize it separately?

Answer (score 3):

kgiannakakis is correct - you should declare `IOCHK` as an integer.

However, there are a few other things that I should point out:

1. After the `OPEN` statement, `IOCHK` will hold the status of the I/O operation, whatever that may be.  You don't need to set a value of `IOCHK` beforehand, as it will simply be discarded.
2. You should use `IMPLICIT NONE` in your code - this will flag undeclared variables like this as compile-time errors, and make hunting down issues like this much easier.
3. After reading this and your other questions, are you writing this code or just maintaining it?  If you're writing it, you probably shouldn't be writing in a style/language version that's older than I am.

Answer (score 1):

IOCHK is neither declared nor initialized in your code. You should have something like this before the OPEN statement:

```
INTEGER IOCHK
IOCHK = 0
```

The above declares an integer variable and assigns a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like not to bother declaring variables you can use the following line at the beginning of your subroutines

```
implicit integer (i-n)
```

This will make all variables that start with letters in the range (i-n) to be declared as integer.

You can of course declare your variable separately at the beginning of the subroutine of interest or you can put it in a module to make it visible by other parts of the code via the `use` statement.

```
   INTEGER :: IOCHK
```

You should also make sure that the status of `IOCHK` is checked only after the file `OPEN` statement, otherwise the whole exercise makes no sense, since IOCHK has not been initialized yet. The values to which the variables are initialized by default are compiler dependent. For instance

```
  program main
  write(*,'(A8,I5)')  'M = ' ,M
  stop
  end program
```

will print `M = 0` with both `ifort` and `gfortran`, but

```
  program main
  write(*,'(A8,ES20.5)')  'M = ' ,M
  stop
  end program
```

will fail with `gfortran` .

In general, I think that you should not have problems if `IOCHK` is not explicitly declared. As an example consider the following code

```
  PROGRAM MAIN
  OPEN(UNIT=4,STATUS='SCRATCH',ACCESS='DIRECT',RECL=2048,IOSTAT=IOCHK)
  IF(IOCHK==0) write(*,'(A8,I5)')  'IOCHK = ' ,IOCHK
  STOP
  END PROGRAM
```

When compiled with both `ifort` and `gfortran` this prints `IOCHK =     0` on the screen, which means that the scratch file was successfully opened.

Hope this helps

Cheers

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking a variable is declared.